# how to get value from one page into another page via URL through session in PHP

Tags: php, session

I am new in PHP and I am doing some work
I have two Page
1) link.php
2) golink.php

link.php

```
<ul>
<li><a href="golink.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="golink.php">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="golink.php">Highlights</a></li>
<li><a href="golink.php">Price</a></li>
<li><a href="golink.php">Location Map</a></li>
<li><a href="golink.php">Payment Plan</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click any link, I want to get the name of that link in golink.php page.
Example:- If I click Home link, I need to get Home value in golink.php page.
I dont want to pass id value in href link like `<a href="golink.php ? value= home">Home</a>` 
I want any other method like session.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: With your current setup, it wouldn't be possible to pass a value without using a GET variable. What you could do is have an individual page for each link (ie `home.php`, `about.php`, etc) and within these pages, set `$value = "home"; (w.e page it is)` and then `include("golink.php")`

Answer (score 0):

use the  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. It will show the previous url.

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the HTTP_REFERER value will not help him... You could mess around by using hidden forms to pass a POST variable, but it's truly not worth it (messy, just not how it should be done).

I'd strongly recommend using a simple elegant (obvious) solution, especially since your new to php and don't want to form too many bad habits early on ;)

Comment: Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: Sucking it up and using $_GET ;-) Piere's suggestion is the best so far. @manas_singh - why is a $_GET variable not an option in your case?

Comment: I want to do it with SESSION. is there any way ?

Comment: Using an Ajax method, calling another page (not the one your going to actually load in the browser window), to pass the variable, so it can be stored in $_SESSION and called when the next page loads. I apologize that I cannot give you code for this off the top of my head :-)

Answer (score 0):

Possible with Javascript.

[Example with Javascript and a cookie](http://jsfiddle.net/DpXDM/)

```
$("a[href='golink.php']").on("click", function(event){
    document.cookie = "linkname="+ escape($(this).text());
});
```

This uses jquery and makes it easier to read. Still not the best solution. Since the visitor needs JS and Cookies enabled. The Skript creates a cookie called "linkname" and you can read the value in golink.php with $_COOKIE['linkname']
Best solution is really a query.

[_COOKIE docs at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)